# Custom IPython magic command for multiple cells

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, customization

How to build a custom IPython magic command that:

1. run a block of code before running a cell;
2. only needs to be called once to be applied on every cell of notebook.

**Similar cases**
`%matplotlib`,
`%pdb`,
`%doctest_mode`

**Example**

```
In [1]: %myMagic 1
Out[1]: myMagic is: ON

In [2]: x = 1
Out[2]: 'Hello World'

In [3]: x
Out[3]: 'Hello World'
   ...:  1

In [4]: %myMagic 0
Out[4]: myMagic is: OFF

In [5]: y=x+1
   ...: y
Out[5]: 2
```

Comment: find documetation for magic commands - maybe there is described how to create own commands.

Comment: @furas, I did that. IPython's documents don't provide further details on customization [link](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/custommagics.html). They only provide a quick introduction to this topic. I looked it up on other sites and what I found are tutorials for basic custom magic commands. Stackoverflow only provides specific cases for customization, based on my research.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on a [Jupyter nbextension](https://github.com/bskinn/jupyter-tempvars) where I want to wrap a code cell's entire contents in a specific context manager before the kernel executes it, where code cells are wrapped or not based upon various user-configurable logic.

As far as I've been able to determine, it's *not possible* to do what you want using magics, because magics aren't able to hook into the execution machinery of the IPython kernel *itself*. As best I know, all of those magics you mention work by changing settings *within some specific module or class*, which then control the global behavior *of that module/class* in the rest of the notebook.

What I've had to do is approach this from the nbextension side, where I fetch the cell code in the frontend Javascript, inject my context manager, indent the block, and *then* submit the edited code for execution by the kernel. For reference, my WIP as of this writing is [here](https://github.com/bskinn/jupyter-tempvars/blob/e26e2d4be42694ba81163c01d0208c9e2f77e66a/src/jupyter_tempvars/extension/jupyter_tempvars.js#L36-L59); a barebones implementation is:

```js
define([
  'notebook/js/codecell'
], function (codecell) {

    "use strict";

    var CodeCell = codecell.CodeCell

    return {
        load_ipython_extension: function () {
            /* Store the original .execute() before overriding,
             * for use in the overridden method
             */ 
            var orig_execute = CodeCell.prototype.execute;

            // Override .execute()
            CodeCell.prototype.execute = function (stop_on_error) {
                var orig_text = this.get_text();
                var new_text = orig_text;

                /* == Make whatever modifications to new_text == */

                /* Rewrite the cell text, make the .execute() call,
                 * and restore the original cell text
                 */
                this.set_text(new_text);
                orig_execute.call(this, stop_on_error);
                this.set_text(orig_text);
            };
        }
    };
});
```